# Change join table by another entity in JPA

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

I have 3 tables: Person, Phone and Person_Phone. Person_Phone is JoinTable for Person and Phone tables.

All the three tables have a primary key.(PostgresSQL sequence). I want to map this using JPA or hibernate annotation. I know to map this relationship using @JoinTable.

But problem is while inserting the data jpa is not able to generate the sequence for Person_Phone(Join Table).

How can I achieve it ??

Below is the table structure

```
Person
-------------
personID(PK)
personName
.....
```

Phone Table:

```
Phone
--------
phoneID
phoneNumber
```

Person_Phone Table:

```
 Person_Phone
 -----------------
 id(PK)
 personID(FK)
 phoneID(FK)
```

Comment: The mapping looks OK so far. Do you have a person field in the Phone entity? Please add it, and also add the code where you try to add the entities and describe precisely what is going wrong.

Comment: sorry kostja . I modified the question please check once.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you do not need a sequence for the join table. Remove it.

Slightly longer answer:

A regular join table has a compound primary key consisting of the ids of the joined entities, in your case, `personID` and `phoneID`.

Remove the `id` column from the table definition, or let hibernate generate the table definitions for you and adapt those as needed.